# Navigation between Activities

Tags: android

I have three activities ( A , B , C ) ,

a button in Activity A sends user to Activity B

and in Activity B , there is another button which sends user to Activity C, also finish() is called on Activity B when that happens.

Now , whenever user presses back button of the device while they are in Activity C , it sends them to Activity A. I don't want this to happen. If users presses back button in Activity C , the app should just finish. or go to "recent screens" tab? whatever you call it. Please help me accomplish this.

Comment: And on clicking back button on Activity B, do you want to go to activity A or you want to exit from app?

Comment: A is parent of B , so clicking back on B should start A . that works fine. But activity C must not have a parent. I didn't declare A as C's parent but it still opens it on back button click.

Comment: you could use startActivityForResult  in activity A and call from activity B and C and avoid this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding onBackPressed in Activity C like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

For older apilevel >= 11 try this when starting Activity C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I will try this now. What does finishAffinity(); do?

Comment: Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but it requires min api level 16 :(

Comment: Oh, sorry i forgot to add that it needs Apilvl 16. What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: How do you start activity C? Can you edit the code in your post above?

Comment: Thanks for the answer tho , i will check other answers now and see what i can do

Comment: i added a solution for apilevel 11, try that

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:
You can finish() A while going to activity B.Then override onBackPress() on activity C and call method finish(); It will finish activity C.

Scenario 2: If you want to finish Activty A only while returning back from C but not from B,finish Activty everytime and on every back Press start Previous activity with intent by overriding it in onBackPress()

eg `

```
onBackPress()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this,prevActivity.class);
startactivty(intent);
finish();
}
```

Another method is when you override onBackPress() insyead os startActivity()
Do startactivityForResult();

and send a code with that.
In every class handle on activity for result and if that particular code exists finish() the activity.`

Answer (score 0):

On click of Activity A's button:

```
 btn_A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        }
});
```

In Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent i=new Intent(B.this,A.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

}       
}
```